# Should I pay for the postdoc position move in flight ticket sweden

Tags: postdocs, sweden

I have a postdoc position in Sweden starting soon and the PI so far haven’t arranged for flight ticket. Is it common for postdoc to buy their own ticket for postdoc in Sweden ?

Comment: Have you asked your boss? Though I think it's unlikely anywhere in the world that they will pay for this kind of thing unless it was part of your contract/appointment letter/etc.

Comment: Do ask your boss. Even if the position comes with relocation assistance, it may be assumed that you buy the ticket and get refunded later.

Comment: I didn’t ask them. Because the position ad didn’t mention any relocation assistance while my previous postdoc also didn’t mention anything about relocation they did buy me flight ticket

Comment: Did you ask? Like, a simple "I fint know how moving works. Do you offer any relocation assistance?" Will probably answer all your questions. If the answer is "no" then you're no worse off than before asking, assuming you're polite and not entitled. (That's usually a good idea at any time!)

Answer (score 7):

I don't know about Sweden specifically, but the idea that the PI would arrange the flights of an incoming postdoc strikes me as very, very unsual. Thus, if this is how a particular postdoc works, I would expect this to be pointed out very explicitly.

There could be some relocation support available, but that would be reimbursing you for tickets you have bought (up to some value, subject to constraints). Moreover, you'd probably have to actively seek this out. Relocation support could be either based on your individual funding source, or on overall university policy.

But as long as you don't learn anything concrete about relocation support, you should assume that it is entirely your own responsibility to arrange and fund your move to Sweden.

Comment: My US  postdoc did pay for my flight ticket that’s why I was wondering if it’s the case for Sweden